# Determining if $\displaystyle (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} <\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n>0$ and such that the following series,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} < \infty.
$$
Is the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded?

The intuition says to me that it must be bounded because if we let it grow, then in someway it would be comparable to the harmonic series which we know it's divergent. But I can't find a nice proof to it or if there's some article or book to read about it.

Comment: It is true that $a_n$ must have a subsequence converging to zero, though! In other words, its $\liminf$ must be $0$. I think the mismatch with your intuition is that "not bounded" doesn't imply "grows" in the sense you might think. (although if you remove the constraint that $a_n > 0$, it is even possible to manufacture examples with $|a_n| \to \infty$ - think about the alternating series test).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your intuition is not correct. Take $$a_n =\begin{cases}2^{k}&\text{if } n = 2^{2k}\\\frac1n & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

This means that $a_n$ becomes

$$1, \frac12, \frac13, 2, \frac15, \frac16, \frac17, \dots, \frac1{15},8,\frac1{17},\dots,\frac1{63},32,\frac1{65},\dots$$

Clearly, $a_n$ is not a bounded sequence. However, the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$$ now becomes becomes an interweaved combination of two sums, one of them being $$\sum \frac1{n^2}$$ with a couple of terms missing, and the other one being $\sum 2^{-k}$.

Since both of them converge, so does their "combination".

Comment: Minor remark, the series $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ is lacunary, but we can upper bound by the full $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ which is convergent, so no issue.

Comment: @zwim You are right, I fixed it.